# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 27896 (JDWP), pid 27888

Tags: android

I try to developing application with android studio. but the app showing error while debugging and always force stop

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 27896 (JDWP), pid 27888 (e.loginretrofit)
```

What error is this? is something wrong my android studio?
Error start from here

```
private void ProcessNow() {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
        dialog.show();

        Call<Book> call = apiInterface.getbooklist(id_book.toString(), startdate.getText().toString(),  enddate.getText().toString()); //this function always return error fatal signal 11 maybe becuase from spinner
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Book>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Book> call, Response<Book> response) {
                String result = response.body().getStatus();
                if(result.equals("true"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(activity_book.this, "Load data successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity_book.this, listbook.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else  if(result.equals("false"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(activity_book.this, "Load Data Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Book> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(activity_book.this, "Something went wrong, Please Try Again !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
```

here is the output of program. Actually i want to showing list view base on id book, start date and end date but it return fatal signal error
[image]

Comment: I have a new android device (android 10) and get this constantly with various apps. I can't return this, so hoping to get some clues.